# How to detect if a process is running on any of the nodes in a multiple node Grid in UNIX

Tags: perl, shell, unix, ps

My server is using a GRID. we have 3 nodes [any one of them could execute my script when i kick off the autosys job ]

Now my problem is if am trying to stop a job from running if it is already running. My code works when i see the scripts is executing on the same node [i mean the first instance and the second instance ]

ps -ead -o %U%p%a| egrep '(ksh|perl)' | grep -v egrep| grep \"perl .*myprocess.pl\"

is there a way, PS could list all instances of the processes from all nodes in the GRID.

please help!!

Comment: you have a 'GRID' which can start jobs on different nodes, but has no job control? strange, to say the least...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a start.flag file in a common location. Keep the below conditions:

> if the flag exists, then the flag will be removed and the
> script will be executed. After completion of execution, the script
> will touch that flag again.
>
> if the flag does not exist, the script will just exit saying that its
> running.

Best luck :)

Comment: Remember, the flag needs to be created manually for the first time.